# Re-install ubuntu without losing install

Tags: partitioning

So, I got my laptop a 500GB hard drive, I originally installed Windows 7 in a dual-boot with Ubuntu, having Windows 7's Partition before Ubuntu's Partition, but due to incompatibility with graphics drivers, I had to remove Windows 7. Now, I got my disk split into 250GB partitions, and I want to migrate my install and reformat the drive to combine these partitions. I backed up the entire root of the machine, excluding the folders /proc and /media using sudo. Is there any way I can erase the machine and re-install without losing anything?

Comment: If you give a link to a gparted screenshot, we could guide you how to manage your partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the first partition and grow the second partition to the size of entire drive. Use GParted from the Ubuntu LiveUSB boot.

No reinstall needed.

(another unrelated small useful thing is to keep /home on separate partition)

Comment: When I tried this, it said that Ubuntu may not boot after the operation.